# Makefile and test-i2p file in C programming

Tags: c, makefile

I already created a Makefile but im not sure if there is something wrong. Can anyone help me.So base on this project.

[image]

```
#######
# Makefile for peep compiler
#######

CC = gcc 
CFLAGS = -O0 -g -Wall -Werror

all: peepcc test-i2p

peepcc: peepcc.o infToPstf.o 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o peepcc peepcc.o infToPstf.o

peepcc.o : peepcc.h infToPstf.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c peepcc.h infToPstf.h 

infToPstf.o : infToPstf.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c infToPstf.h 

test-i2p:
    echo "This is the test-i2p target"

clean:
    rm -f *.o *~ peepcc 
    rm -rf *.dSYM
    (cd traces; rm -f *~)
```

infToPstf.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "infToPstf.h"
#include "peepcc.h"
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
....
code here
```

infToPstf.h:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "peepcc.h"

.... 
code here
```

peepcc.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "infToPstf.h"
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "peepcc.h"
```

peepcc.h:

```
#ifndef PEEPCC_H_
#define PEEPCC_H_

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
```

Thank you.
Also What should the test file test-i2p looks like. I tried to search for test file for C programming but cant find any related. Thank you

I tried to create a Makefile already. But Im not sure if there something wrong

Comment: a fairly common issue could be using spaces when there should be tabs in the `Makefile` .. if you're getting an error, what is it? do you have an awkward env for programming like Windows?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: The `peepcc.o` and `infToPstf.o` rules look weird.  Do you really want to compile header files?

Comment: If you need more help than the answer that I provided, please update question so it's a [mre] (snippets means we have to do a bunch of extra work to help you).  Explain what the problem is, and what you expect.  The image doesn't add anything so I suggest you remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Makefile and let me know how it goes Make sure you use tab to indent the @echo and rm lines):

```
.PHONY: all clean test-i2p
CC = gcc 
CFLAGS = -O0 -g -Wall -Werror

all: peepcc test-i2p

peepcc: peepcc.o infToPstf.o 

peepcc.o: peepcc.c peepcc.h infToPstf.h

infToPstf.o: infToPstf.c infToPstf.h

test-i2p:
    @echo "This is the test-i2p target"

clean:
    rm -f *.o *~ peepcc traces/*~
    rm -rf *.dSYM
```